# Almost split sequences for symmetric algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, modules, short-exact-sequences, pullback, symmetric-algebras

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and $A$ be a symmetric algebra.
I want to know how to compute almost split sequences ending at a non-projective indecomposable right $A$-module $X$.

Question: Let $P\xrightarrow{p} \Omega(M)$ be the projective cover of $\Omega(X)$, where $\Omega(X)$ is the first syzygy of $X$. Then, we have an exact sequence

$0\to \Omega ^2(X) \to P \xrightarrow{p} \Omega(X)\to 0$.

Now, let $\xi \in \underline{\mathsf{Hom}} _A(X,\Omega(X))$ such that $\xi$ generates the socle of  $\underline{\mathsf{Hom}} _A(X,\Omega(X))$.
Then, we can take pullback along $(p,\xi)$, and we have an exact sequence

$0\to \Omega^2(X)\to E \to X \to 0$.

My question is: Is the exact sequence $0\to \Omega^2(X)\to E \to X \to 0$ almost split?

Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. You can read about it in my Representations and Cohomology I, section 4.12.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I understood that the almost split sequence ending at $X$ is represented by a generator of simple socle of the stable endomorphism ring of $X$.
But, why is the exact sequence from the pull-back along $(p,\xi)$ almost split?

Comment: No, it's the simple socle of the *dual* of the stable endomorphism ring. Use Tate duality, which is Auslander-Reiten duality in this case, to see that this is your stable homs. Then translating to Ext$^1$ is standard dimension shifting, and yours is one of the equivalent ways to do it.